# What does "Its’ less about being intellectual and more about focusing on wealth accumulation" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Its’ less about being intellectual and more about focusing on wealth accumulation"

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2018/04/24/31-year-old-millionaire-heres-the-no-1-downside-to-being-rich.html
(the video is at the bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, to be grammatically correct, the sentence should be.

> **It's** less about being intellectual and more about focusing on wealth accumulation

which means

> It is about focusing on wealth accumulation more than it is about being intellectual.